# Using variables in printf format

Tags: printf, awk

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
$ cat a
hello this is a sentence
and this is another one
```

And I want to print the first two columns with some padding in between them. As this padding may change, I can for example use `7`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%7-s%s\n", $1, $2}' a
hello  this
and    this
```

Or `17`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%17-s%s\n", $1, $2}' a
hello            this
and              this
```

Or `25`, or... you see the point: the number may vary.

Then a question popped: is it possible to assign a variable to this `N`, instead of hardcoding the integer in the `%N-s` format?

I tried these things without success:

```
$ awk '{n=7; printf "%{n}-s%s\n", $1, $2}' a
%{n}-shello
%{n}-sand

$ awk '{n=7; printf "%n-s%s\n", $1, $2}' a
%n-shello
%n-sand
```

Ideally I would like to know if it is possible to do this. If it is not, what would be the best workaround?

Comment: oh! fedorqui asked a question!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use  `*` in your format string, it gets a number from the arguments

```
awk '{printf "%*-s%s\n", 17, $1, $2}' file
hello            this
and              this
```

```
awk '{printf "%*-s%s\n", 7, $1, $2}' file
hello  this
and    this
```

---

As read in [The GNU Awk User’s Guide #5.5.3 Modifiers for printf Formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers):

> The C library printf’s dynamic width and prec capability (for example,
>   "%*.*s") is supported. Instead of supplying explicit width and/or prec
>   values in the format string, they are passed in the argument list. For
>   example:

```
w = 5
p = 3
s = "abcdefg"
printf "%*.*s\n", w, p, s
```

> is exactly equivalent to:

```
s = "abcdefg"
printf "%5.3s\n", s
```

Comment: Splendid, yes! Do you have any source explaining this behaviour?

Comment: don't know this. +1 dude

Comment: @fedorqui Sure, it is stated [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers)

Comment: These and the positional specifiers are my favorite underused (and under-supported) specifiers.

Comment: This has what I really like of answers: discovers a functionality that I did not know about and opens new fields and opportunities. Thanks a lot @jaypal!

Comment: All I could do was sit back and click the +1 ... :-). Y'know what functionality doesn't exist that I wish did though - to be able to specify any lead character when padding. Just like you can do `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%05d\n",17}'` to left-pad with zeros, it'd often be convenient if you could do `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%#5d\n",17}'` to pad with `#`s or any other character. That way if you wanted a string of 5 `#`s you could simply do `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%#5d\n",""}'` instead of `awk 'BEGIN{print gensub(/0/,"#","g",sprintf("%05d",""))}'` or similar. Oh well there we'd go towards language bloat again..

Answer (score 6):

does this count?

idea is building the "dynamic" `fmt`, used for `printf`.

```
kent$   awk '{n=7;fmt="%"n"-s%s\n"; printf fmt, $1, $2}' f 
hello  this
and    this
```

Comment: Good idea! Quite similar to konsolebox, only that you use "model-view-controller" pattern :)

Comment: My preferred solution out the answers. Example: `git log --pretty=%ae | awk '{ n=length($1) ; if (n>l) l=n ; arr[tolower($1)]++ } END { fmt="%-"l"s: %4i\n" ; for (i in arr) printf(fmt, i, arr[i]) | "sort" }'` - Meaning, calculate the max length of the git author to use in the END block printf.

Answer (score 4):

Using simple string concatenation.

Here `"%"`, `n` and `"-s%s\n"` concatenates as a single string for the format. Based on the example below, the format string produced is `%7-s%s\n`.

```
awk -v n=7 '{ printf "%" n "-s%s\n", $1, $2}' file
awk '{ n = 7; printf "%" n "-s%s\n", $1, $2}' file
```

Output:

```
hello  this
and    this
```

Comment: Nice! This seems to be making it. Would you mind adding some explanation for future readers?

Comment: Many thanks, I would have selected this answer if jaypal's answer did not appear. Clear and well explained, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can use eval (maybe not the most beautiful with all the escape characters, but it works)

```
i=15
eval "awk '{printf \"%$i-s%s\\n\", \$1, \$2}' a"
```

output:

```
hello          this
and            this
```

Comment: Yes, good one, although I was looking for something "fully awk specific".

Comment: at least it is versatile for other commands where you would like to do something similar...