# Solve a puzzle using bash tools such as grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I need to solve a puzzle using shell script. I tried to combine **grep** with **rev** and saved the output into a temporary text file but still don't know how to solve it entirely.

That's the puzzle to solve :

```
j s e t f l
a l s f e l
g a a n p l
e p f d p k
r e g e l a
f n e t e n
```

The file that contains the wordlist to use is in http://pastebin.com/DP4mFZAr

I know how to tell grep where to find the patterns to match as fixed strings extracted from a text file using  `$ grep -Ff wordlist puzzle` and
how to search for mirrored words using `$ rev puzzle |  grep -Ff wordlist puzzle` , thus dealing with the horizontal lines, but how do I deal with vertical words too ?

Comment: A quick comment: `grep` _is not_ a “Bash tool”.

Comment: So now that you have the answer, was this homework?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am covering horizontal and vertical matching. The main idea is to remove the spaces and then use `grep -f` with the given list of words, stored in `words` file.

With `grep -f`, the results are shown within the line. If you just want to see the matched test, use `grep -of`.

#### Horizontal matching

```
$ cat puzzle | tr -d ' ' | grep -f words
alsfel
gaanpl
regela
fneten

$ cat puzzle | tr -d ' ' | grep -of words
als
gaan
regel
eten
```

#### Vertical matching

For this, we firstly have to transpose the content of the file. For this, I use what I used for [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25062537/1983854):

```
transpose () {
  awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i; max=(max<NF?NF:max)}
        END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++)
              {for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) 
                  printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j<NR?OFS:ORS)
              }
        }'
}
```

And let's see:

```
$ cat puzzle | transpose | tr -d ' ' | grep -f words
jagerf
slapen
esafge
tfndet
lllkan

$ cat puzzle | transpose | tr -d ' ' | grep -of words
jager
slapen
af
ge
de
kan
```

You can then use `rev` (as you suggest in your question) for mirrored words. Also `tac` can be interesting for vertically mirrored words.

#### Diagonal matching

For the diagonal matching, I think that an interesting approach would be to move every single line a little bit to the left/right. This way,

```
e x x x x
x g x x x
x x g x x
```

can become

```
e x x x x
g x x x
g x x
```

and you can use the vertical/horizontal approaches.

For this, you can use `printf` as described in [Using variables in printf format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408074/1983854):

```
$ cat a
e x x x x
x g x x x
x x g x x
$ awk -v c=20 '{printf "%*s\n", c, $0; c-=2}' a
        e x x x x
        x g x x x
    x x g x x
```

Comment: Dude I love you. Do you have Paypal? I'd like to buy you a beer.

Comment: Haha you are welcome. Yes, I would ask for a La Chouffe :D I added some explanation about how to match diagonally.

Comment: PM me your Paypal and I'll get you money for a La Chouffe!

Comment: Absolutely off-topic here, but man! you have great tastes! La Chouffe is one of my favorite beers too!

Comment: You guys should try 'Kasteel Cuvée du Château'. Its quite wonderful (also not for the faint of heart- its 11,6%).

Comment: @Menubalk uhms, will keep that one in memory. This is the best present you can give me: a set of names of beers to try!

Comment: Kasteel Donker is another beer of similiar strength. You can also try Kwak bier and La Trappe Tripel :).

Also, I made a shell script out of your solution, but for some reason it doesn't work.. here it is: 
http://pastebin.com/3K0S23qG

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for all your help anyway! and enjoy the beers, haha